# Navigation with fragments in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let me describe situtation : 
I have activity that has navigation drawer that has items A, B, C, D, S(PreferencesFragment). Now as user goes into app he can choose whatever he wants. Lets say he click on B this opens new fragmentB that has list of some items. Clicking on item opens new fragmentDetails and puts transaction of fragments to back stack to enable user to go back to fragmentB with list.
Let user still be on fragmentDetails, if he now chooses to go to fragmentS from nav. drawer I would like the back stack to be empty. Is there any way how to let back stack to forget about remaining transactions ? I dont mean like popBackStack, becouse this would result into for a some small amont of time showing fragmentB.

How to achive this kind of navigation ?

Comment: don't add the fragment to the back stack. don't so `ft.addtobackstack(null)`

Comment: but I want user to be able to go from fragmentDetails to fragmentB with back button

Comment: so what is that you want. Its not clear

Comment: FragmentB --> DetailsFragment. DetailsFragment back button. FragmentB. Now FragmentB--> FragmentS. don't add the fragment to the backstack at this point if i understand your problem rightly

Comment: okay I dont do that like you described ... but FragmentB->Details transaction goes to backstack. from Details->fragmentS(from drawer), from fragmentS to fragmentB via drawer again and transaction is in backstackk still ... this is what I mean

Comment: fragmentS to fragmentB  Don't add the fragment to the backstack now.

Comment: I dont ! I only add fragments to backstack if from fragmentB->Details I never use addtobackstack method to keep track of transactions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50627/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-xoolooo)

Answer (score 0):

lupajz,
please take some time to consider on which fragments the user will have access to the navigation drawer. Most of the time when you reach a "item details" fragment you may wan't to offer a different kind of navigation.

What you want to achieve can be done using this line:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Nevertheless please take a look at the following blog posts I've written covering this issues:

https://aarcoraci.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/android-tutorial-drawer-and-fragment-navigation-made-easyier/

https://aarcoraci.wordpress.com/2017/02/14/android-drawer-and-fragment-navigation-a-more-real-life-scenario/